# Calling NSLog in LLVM bitcode makes runtime error in iOS

Tags: ios, llvm

I'm making LLVM pass for Mach-O files with bitcode. For debugging purposes, I'd like to make a pass that adds log. So that I can see the logs after ipa file with bitcode is uploaded to test flight and installed to an iPhone.

What I was planning was to make a call to NSLog with function name and implemented the pass like following based on other codes. However this code crashes when it's ran on the iPhone. How should I edit the code so that it prints log without any problems. Following are current llvm pass code and error on runtime.

LLVM PASS CODE:

```
    Function *Nslog = module->getFunction("NSLog");
    if (!Nslog) {
        PointerType *Pty = PointerType::get(IntegerType::get(module->getContext(), 8), 0);
        FunctionType *FuncTy = FunctionType::get(Pty, true);

        Nslog = Function::Create(FuncTy, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, "NSLog", module);
        Nslog->setCallingConv(CallingConv::Swift);
    }

    IRBuilder <> builder(module->getContext());
    builder.SetInsertPoint(bb);
    llvm::Value *strPointer = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(func_name+2);

    const std::vector<llvm::Value *> args{strPointer};
    IRBuilder<> logCall(bb->getFirstNonPHI());
    logCall.CreateCall(Nslog, args);
```

Crash Log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
VM Region Info: 0x1 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4331290623
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 00000001022a4000-00000001022a8000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...Depth-Sampler

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [2208]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001bc347b28 objc_msgSend + 8
1   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001bc1decc4 os_log_shim_with_CFString + 80 (format.m:24)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bc6166b8 _CFLogvEx3 + 184 (CFUtilities.c:1165)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001bc9f86fc _NSLogv + 120 (NSPlatform.m:0)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001bc9f8740 NSLog + 48 (NSPlatform.m:1305)
5   iOS-Depth-Sampler               0x00000001022ab328 main + 44 (VideoCapture.swift:0)
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001bc4298f0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001bc343738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000001   x1: 0x00000001f7b86238   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x000000016db5ba00   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000ffffffff
    x8: 0x00000001f7b86000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x00000001bc438f20  x11: 0x00000001fd5ffd30
   x12: 0x000000010264d360  x13: 0x0000000102308000  x14: 0x000000008b23e000  x15: 0x000000000000007c
   x16: 0x00000001bc32effc  x17: 0x000000000b200000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001bc6166b8
   x20: 0x000000016db5ba00  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x000000020966c9c0  x23: 0x00000001022ab328
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x00000001022ab328  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016db5ba68   fp: 0x000000016db5b920   lr: 0x00000001bc1decc4
    sp: 0x000000016db5b8f0   pc: 0x00000001bc347b28 cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

for people who meet same problem, I'll leave how I made NSLog calls in ipa's LLVM.
In XCode Project I added tons of NSLog calls. Then in bitcode level, we can find NSLog call functions like following

```
  tail call swiftcc void @"$s10Foundation5NSLogyySS_s7CVarArg_pdtF"(i64 -3458764513820540907, %"__ir_hidden#293_"* inttoptr (i64 or (i64 sub (i64 ptrtoint ([22 x i8]* @12 to i64), i64 32), i64 -9223372036854775808) to %"__ir_hidden#293_"*), %"__ir_hidden#293_"* bitcast (%"__ir_hidden#275_"* @_swiftEmptyArrayStorage to %"__ir_hidden#293_"*)), !dbg 413
```

Since !dbg part has limited scope of function (not sure, experimental result) remove !dbg part and get rest of NSLog function call. I linked all bitcode files in Mach-O and made it to a single .bc file. In this .bc file, I could move above instruction in other function to call NSLog at wanted position.
Also, at bitcode level, I could change value of global string and set it as wanted value. (not at runtime)